# How to install Django in virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and setup my environment like this

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo mkdir /vc
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /vc
cd /vc/
virtualenv --no-site-packages cb-env
cd cb-env/
source bin/activate
```

It all works and I see (cb-env)ubuntu@ip:
now when I try to install django without sudo it fails:

```
pip install django

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/vc/cb-env/build/django'
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: The only command that needs sudo is the first one, all others you should run as your normal user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could re-set ownership, with chown -R (= --recursive): sudo chown -R yourusername /vc